# req.body undefined in expressjs4.x

Tags: node.js, express

I have looked read through all the answers on SO about this, but nothing seem to be working.

Here is my `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    

var about = require('./routes/about');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/about', about);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.locals.pretty = true;
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

And here is my `about.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('about');    
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Called");
    console.log(req.body); // this is always undefined

    //below variables are also undefined
var name = req.body.contactName, 
        email = req.body.contactEmail,
        message = req.body.contactMessage,
        subj = req.body.contactSub;

});


module.exports = router;
```

I have spent considerable time moving around the declarations in `app.js` file as suggested in many SO answers but I think I have just lucked out. I am certainly doing something wrong but can't find it. Note that I am a relative beginner to the nodejs world.

Here is `req.headers`

```
{ host: 'debian:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '0',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  origin: 'http://debian:3000',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  referer: 'http://debian:3000/about',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' }
```

**Update**
I missed adding `name` to my form, this caused this problem. Thanks to @t.niese for suggesting this.

Comment: You are showing the headers, but where do to do your post?

Comment: Your code looks fine, but the  `content-length` of the request is  `0`, are you sure that you have any named input elements in your form? You could test your code directly using `curl -i -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://localhost:3000/about`  and check if the console prints out the params correctly `{ param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }`.

Comment: Please post your view with the form that submits to your about router.

Comment: @t.niese - I did not put in the `name` in my form. How stupid of me. Thanks. Please put in your suggestion as an answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circumstance that the `content-length` header has the value `0` tells you that the client did not send any data within the body of the request. As of that you need to look for the problem on the client side, because you expect that there is some data within the body.

There could be different reasons for it one - and out of the comment this was actually the problem - is that you forgot to give the form element(s) a name.